# Oracle/SQL: Pull all data from the right of a ':' OR a '/', which ever comes first

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for help with trying to figure out how I can re-write the following SQL to extract anything that comes after the first instance of a colon (:) or slash (/) coming from the right side of the field.

I currently use something like the below, but that will only pull from after the colon (:) and I want it to look for a slash (/) too:

```
select substr(DBURL,instr(DBURL,':',-1)+1) as DB
from databasename;
```

Examples of data in the DBURL field:

```
trld:client:blah:data
trld:client:blah/data
```

I am only looking to extract the data portion of the sting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/ap_posix.htm#i691974), specifically [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#sthref1429) for this.

```
select regexp_substr(DBURL,            --source string
                    '[^:/]+$'          --pattern that you are looking for
                    ) as DB 
  from databasename;
```

Breaking down the pattern,

```
[^:/]  : match anything other than a colon or slash.
+      : match the preceding pattern one or more times
$      : match the end of the string.
```

Putting it togather, this pattern matches anything other than a colon or slash at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap two of your `instr` into `greatest`.

```
11:17:02 (20)SYSTEM@dwal> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\dwal\BUF_SYSTEM_20.sql

  1  with databasename(dburl) as (
  2   select 'trld:client:blah:data' from dual union all
  3   select 'trld:client:blah\data' from dual
  4  )
  5  select substr(DBURL,greatest(instr(DBURL,'\',-1), instr(DBURL,':',-1))+1) as DB
  6* from databasename
11:17:14 (20)SYSTEM@dwal> /

DB
---------------------
data
data

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10
```

RegEx is ok either, but slower.